# assign angular theme classname with a variable

Tags: angular

I have 4 themes the I allow the user to select from for my angular app. I then want to assign the string corresponding to that theme to the main div that contains the app. I can do it manually by changing

```
<div class="dark-theme"> or
<div class="default-theme"> etc.
```

What I want to be able to do is set the classname for the theme from a variable I pull from the app-settings. e.g.
(component.ts)

```
this.theme = this.settings.theme
```

(component.html)

```
<div class={{theme}}>
```

I've tried [ngClass], [className], {{theme}}, '{{theme}}' and a bunch of other variations but nothing work. I know I'm passing the correct theme name to the html since I can also display it in a \p> element. All the reading I've done keeps referring to using a conditional with ngClass. Are you not able to just assign the string directly from the contents/value of a string variable in the component typescript?

Thanks....

Comment: `<div class="{{theme}}">` (you're missing the double quotes)

Comment: Nope, doesn't change the theme. If I type class="dark-theme" manually it works. But my paragraph tag displays ' "dark-theme"  ' as the variable value though so I know its getting in.

Comment: [Check this little sample.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nezbsf) No reason it wouldn't work. Check the final HTML by browsing the source (Ctrl+U on most browsers)

Comment: am getting the correct theme into the html. But it is not changing the theme when I change the class. Even tried reloading the page manually and theme still doesn't take.

Comment: If the final HTML is correct, then it's not Angular-related. Your browser has no idea whether the class name is hardcoded or comes from a variable.

Comment: @Jeto is correct. i updated his answer a little bit to demonstrate that changing a CSS theme via his solution is no problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdg2d7

Comment: got it! Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<div [ngClass]="theme"/>
```

Try this